# Whats the trick in javascript Array.findIndex

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I was trying to simulate random by probabilities, and found something interesting with `Array.findIndex`

```js
const probabilities = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3];
const thresholds = probabilities.reduce((r, p, i) => r.concat((r[i - 1] || 0) + p), []);

const f1 = () => thresholds.findIndex(x => x > Math.random());
const f2 = () => {
    const r = Math.random();
    for (let i = 0; i < thresholds.length; i++)
        if (r < thresholds[i])
            return i;
    return -1;
};

const run = (f) => Array.from(Array(1000000), f).reduce((r, x) => Object.assign(r, { [x]: 1 + (r[x] || 0) }), {});

run(f1);
run(f2);
```

The output results were like

```
{ "0": 100210, "1": 269763, "2": 377463, "-1": 252564 }
{ "0": 99381,  "1": 199927, "2": 300408, "-1": 400284 }
```

Apparently the `Array.findIndex` paired with `Math.random` was not working as I supposed.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, Please go read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Code relevant to your problem belongs directly to your question, in text form and properly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing against a new, different random number every time, so the results are unpredictable. In your second function you don't do that, you create one number and save it to `r` and then check all thresholds with it.

You can do the same with `findIndex` as well:

```js
const f1 = () => {
  const r = Math.random();
  return thresholds.findIndex(x => x > r);
};
```